# Implicit conversions in row.getAs[Long]

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

When I try to apply a filter function on a dataframe , I have met a confused problem.

If the fields of a row are `null`, `isNotNull1` will be false, and `isNotNull2` will be true. Here is the code:

```
      val res = df.filter(row => {
        val isNotNull1 = (row.getAs[Long]("video_id") != null)
        val videoId = row.getAs[Long]("video_id")
        val isNotNull2 = (videoId != null)
        isNotNull2
      })
```

Idea debug result:
[image]

I can understand `isNotNull2` is true, as the doc of `getAs[T](fieldName: String)` says `For primitive types if value is null it returns 'zero value' specific for primitive`.

Are there scala implicit conversions happened here? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is that generics don't *really* work with primitive types. The Scala compiler tries to present the illusion that they do but you've stumbled on a case where it fails.

So `row.getAs[Long]("video_id")` is "really" `row.getAs[java.lang.Long]("video_id")` which returns `null` in your case, so the `val isNotNull1` line compares `null != null` which is false.

In the `val videoId` line, because its type is `Long`, it becomes `row.getAs[java.lang.Long]("video_id").asInstanceOf[Long]`. This is `0`, and in the next line you do `0.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Long] != null` which is true.

Answer (score 0):

The Scala compiler can often infer the type of an expression so we don’t have to declare it explicitly.

While evaluating val isNotNull1 = (row.getAsLong != null) **row.getAsLong is null** and null != null is false.
While evaluating val videoId = row.getAsLong **row.getAsLong will still be null** however compiler infer it is a Long and null will be assign to 0 because primitive could not be null.

Also, in the below code, videoId_wrong will throw a compiler error it is a Long and has been explicitly inferred as String.

```
val res = df.filter(row => {
  val isNotNull1 = (row.getAs[Long]("video_id") != null)
  val videoId_wrong: String = row.getAs[Long]("video_id")
  val videoId = row.getAs[Long]("video_id")
  val isNotNull2 = (videoId != null)
  isNotNull2
})
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/type-inference.html